# React Material-UI Datagrid error issue After building a App

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, readonly-attribute

I'm in trouble now. because of error below.
Before building my App, A console is fine. but after building, A console logs error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om4HJ.png)

as i think, it's cause is row data in Data-grid. because A console logs read-only error.
the row data is read-only array. so i think it's problematic.
please help me..! thank you have a good day guys

my Data-grid code

```
        <DataGrid
      rows={Array.from(chatListData)}
      columns={ChatRoomColumns}
      pageSize={10}
      rowHeight={75}
      sx={DataGridStyle}
      checkboxSelection
      selectionModel={selectionModel}
      onSelectionModelChange={onSelectionModelChange}
      disableSelectionOnClick
      filterMode="client"
      components={{
        Toolbar: () => <Headers data={chatListData} />,
        Pagination: () => (
          <Footer
            chatData={rowUrl}
            setRowUrl={setRowUrl}
            getList={getList}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. I fixed it by downgrading the version of *@material-ui/data-grid*.  I had *4.0.0-alpha.37* then downgraded to *4.0.0-alpha.35* and the issue was solved. Also, make sure the *react version* being used meets the *@material-ui/data-grid* dependency.